# VLC 2.1.5 - OSX Mavericks - Disable Media Library?

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player

I'm wondering if it's possible to stop VLC 2.1.5 from automatically adding media played from the computer into the "Media Library". It's possible to delete each file after it's added, however it's annoying having to do so.

VLC -> Preferences -> Show All -> Playlist -> Use media library is currently *unchecked* however files are still automatically added on playback.

Otherwise options should be pretty much default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but if others have this issue, try this:

Preferences -> Show All -> Interface -> macosx -> Keep Recent Items <- Un-check this box

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your VLC preferences in ~/Library/Preferences (there are files and possibly a sub-folder in there!).  My VLC does NOT save the Media Library.  I tried turning ON that pref, and it caused VLC to crash.  In fact, VLC crashes every time I quit it now.  I'd say that pref is corrupt (VLC bug).  I deleted my prefs, and VLC is no longer crashing on quit.  Hope that helps you!